# Reliable SMS service

Tags: web-services, sms

I'm looking for a reliable service that offers an API to send SMS. This is intended for rather low volume usage, sending single SMS, so no need for bulk sending or bulk discounts. It should provide

- Reliable Delivery
- REST API or client library
- Easy and quick registration
- Reasonable price (<=0.1 EUR/SMS)

A google search turns up a ton of services, but it's hard to tell how trustworthy and reliable those are. I already know about Twilio and MessageBird, but I'm looking for further alternatives.

Comment: what are the reasons for not going with Twilio and MessageBird?

Comment: @lakshman I was evaluating possible providers, and there's a myriad of providers with rather dubious appearance and varying performance. Hard to find the good ones. Also I want to use different providers for redundancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use IntelliSMS, and have used it for many years with much success https://www.intellisms.co.uk/

Comment: Thanks for that option, didn't know about them until now